# Creating expiring links to S3 or Cloudfront hosted content with ASP .Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Anyone have an example of creating a signed URL with an expiration using ASP .Net?  I'm exploring using [LitS3](http://code.google.com/p/lits3/) or [ThreeSharp](http://www.codeplex.com/ThreeSharp) in my project, and have not seen any specific methods to do this in either of those projects.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what worked for me with the AWS SDK and MVC 3 (based on the answers above and what I found on http://www.ec2studio.com/articles/s3.html):

```
public ActionResult GetS3Object(string bucket, string key)
{
    string accessKeyID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSAccessKey"];
    string secretAccessKeyID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSSecretKey"];
    using (AmazonS3 client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(accessKeyID, secretAccessKeyID))
        {
        GetPreSignedUrlRequest request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest()
            .WithBucketName(bucket)
            .WithKey(key)
            .WithExpires(DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0)));
        return Redirect(client.GetPreSignedURL(request));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

using the amazon .net SDK
you can get preSignedUrl

```
using (AmazonS3 client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client("your access key ID", "you secret key"))
            {
                GetPreSignedUrlRequest getPreSignedUrl = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest().WithBucketName(bucketName);
                getPreSignedUrl.Key = key;
                getPreSignedUrl.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Found [this](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/servlet/JiveServlet/download/24-36128-143603-2695/code.txt) (mentioned in [this](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/thread.jspa?messageID=143603&tstart=0) thread in the AWS discussion forums) class library for generating signed URLs in Amazon S3. If anyone has any additional suggestions/methods to try, let me know.

Edit:  ThreeSharp has the functionality I was looking for.  From the ThreeSharpConsoleSample app:

```
      using (UrlGetRequest request = new UrlGetRequest("mytestbucket", "mytestfile.txt"))
            {
                request.ExpiresIn = 60 * 10000;
                using (UrlGetResponse response = service.UrlGet(request))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Try this url in your web browser (it will only work for 60 seconds)\n");
                    string url = response.StreamResponseToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(url);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\npress enter >");
            Console.ReadLine();
```