# Hide source of file download hosted on Amazon S3 using MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, upload, download, amazon-s3

I have a question related to my ASP.net MVC 3 application. My web app allows users to upload files to Amazon S3 and other members to access them. I wish to have control over who can access these file.  To do this I dont want to expose the URI's of the files and I would perfer not to have the server proxy the file.

Can someone suggest the best ways to achieve this?

Comment: I can't think of a solution that wouldn't defeat the purpose of using a CDN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 allows you to create a signed url which has a time expiration.  This appears to have been covered completely here:  [Creating expiring links to S3 or Cloudfront hosted content with ASP .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607805/creating-expiring-links-to-s3-or-cloudfront-hosted-content-with-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use the AWS SDK for .NET and call the [GetPreSignedURL method](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_S3_AmazonS3_GetPreSignedURL.htm) which will generate a temporary url with querystring authorization.  Another option would be to point your images to a secured MVC route which does a 301/302 redirect to the image url (could also be a presigned url).